# Cordova app not building for Windows Phone 8 due to file-transfer plug-in

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8

I have a Cordova app which runs on Android, iOS and Windows Phone 8 platforms. After making updates to the app which required the addition of additional plug-ins, I am unable to perform a build for Windows Phone 8 due to a compilation error within its version of the *org.apache.cordova.file-transfer* plug-in. This is the output when attempting a build:

```
$ cordova build wp8
Running command: cmd "/s /c ""D:\MyPhonegapProject\platforms\wp8\cordova\build.bat"""

Building project: D:/MyPhonegapProject/platforms/wp8/MyPhonegapApp.sln
        Configuration : debug
        Platform      : any cpu
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
Plugins\org.apache.cordova.file-transfer\FileTransfer.cs(445,26): error CS0426: The type name 'FileEntry' does not exist in the type 'System.IO.File' [D:\MyPhonegapProject\platforms\wp8\MyPhonegapApp.csproj]
Plugins\org.apache.cordova.file-transfer\FileTransfer.cs(445,49): error CS0117: 'System.IO.File' does not contain a definition for 'FileEntry' [D:\MyPhonegapProject\platforms\wp8\MyPhonegapApp.csproj]
Plugins\org.apache.cordova.file-transfer\FileTransfer.cs(452,96): error CS0117: 'System.IO.File' does not contain a definition for 'NOT_FOUND_ERR' [D:\MyPhonegapProject\platforms\wp8\MyPhonegapApp.csproj]
Plugins\org.apache.cordova.file-transfer\FileTransfer.cs(631,26): error CS0426: The type name 'FileEntry' does not exist in the type 'System.IO.File' [D:\MyPhonegapProject\platforms\wp8\MyPhonegapApp.csproj]
Plugins\org.apache.cordova.file-transfer\FileTransfer.cs(631,53): error CS0426: The type name 'FileEntry' does not exist in the type 'System.IO.File' [D:\MyPhonegapProject\platforms\wp8\MyPhonegapApp.csproj]
ERROR: Error code 1 for command: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\msbuild with args: D:/MyPhonegapProject/platforms/wp8/MyPhonegapApp.sln,/clp:NoSummary;NoItemAndPropertyList;Verbosity=minimal,/nologo,/p:Configuration=debug,/p:Platform=any cpu
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 2
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 2
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:131:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)
```

As the error messages indicate, the issue stems from references in the plug-in's native code to apparently non-existent members of the System.IO.File class. These references [can be seen](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/blob/master/src/wp/FileTransfer.cs#L445) in the plug-in source hosted on Github. Builds for both Android and iOS work fine.

Has anyone else encountered this issue, and if so, how did you resolve it?

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this. It was caused by another plug-in, *org.apache.cordova.file*, missing its single *File.cs* source file from the *Plugins\org.apache.cordova.file* directory. I copied it from Github into my solution and now it builds without any problem.